# Prometheus pod crashlooping on error "opening storage failed"

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, prometheus-operator

I restarted the Prometheus pod and now the Prometheus pod is crashlooping. Found this error in the logs:

```
level=error ts=2021-06-09T09:27:29.066Z caller=main.go:758 err="opening storage failed: block dir: \"/prometheus/01F6J0P4KBBWVJD2M8B1PE7C5E\": open /prometheus/01F6J0P4KBBWVJD2M8B1PE7C5E/meta.json: no such file or directory"
```

Noticed that the `01F6J0P4KBBWVJD2M8B1PE7C5E` folder only has the chunks folder in it.

Any idea why this occurs and is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you have already found correct github related issues and asked there also.

- [Still seeing "opening storage failed: block dir" on more recent version of prometheus #7090](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/7090)
- [does not start up after corrupted meta.json file](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/4058)

And seems currently the only way to fix the problem is to delete `01F6J0P4KBBWVJD2M8B1PE7C5E` folder that contains empty `meta.json` either nothing ([link](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/4058#issuecomment-426290403))

Comment: Yes, that was the only way to get the pod running.